# Android Load Image From URL Into ListView

Tags: android

I have a ListView onto which I would like to load image from url where images names are an ID.jpg (eg: 1.jpg / 2.jpg / 3.jpg.. etc). The IDs are from the database, however the images loaded into my ListView for all rows is one image (1.jpg).

```
txtDate.setText(Request_Date.get(position));
txtTime.setText(Request_Time.get(position));

//ivImage.setImageResource(imgid[position]); <-- this works from drawable and not from database

Picasso.with(context).load(url_poster + request_eventID + ".jpg").into(ivImage);
```

The `request_eventID` are IDs from DB, this is my problem, it only returns 1 (and not the rest of the IDs) so therefore only 1.jpg is loaded into the ListView on all rows.

EDIT:

How I retrieve IDs

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("read_columns");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
String request_date = jsonChildNode.optString("Date");
String request_time = jsonChildNode.optString("Time");
request_eventID = jsonChildNode.optString("EID");

arrRequest_Date.add(request_date);
arrRequest_Time.add(request_time);
arrRequest_EID.add(request_eventID);
```

Note that I can see all IDs if I do a `System.out.println("IDs" +request_eventID)`

Comment: whats is your sql query to retrieve data

Comment: Please post where and how are you getting "request_eventID" ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just as I suspected, I played around with the code a bit and indeed get(position) was what I needed on the IDs.

Solution:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url_poster + Request_EID.get(position) + ".jpg").into(ivImage);
```

Thank you all for responding.